# MySql - Update the defualt table schema on production server

Tags: mysql, alter-table, mysql-5.0

The story starts with a MySql table called `table` on the production server:

[image]

As you can see, I f***ed up when specifying defaults - `0000-00-00 00:00:00` is not a valid MySql datetime.

I need to change all the `Datetime Defaults => 1000-01-01 00:00:00`

I also need to change some of the `Null` column values.

If I go ahead and run the script to do this:

```
ALTER table
CHANGE COLUMN
date_created DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '1000-01-01 00:00:00:',
date_lastmodified DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '1000-01-01 00:00:00',
so on...;
```

Do I run the risk of corrupting data in the database?

`MySql Version 5.0.4-beta-nt`

Comment: Are you really using `5.0.4-beta-nt` on production? That does not sound like a GA version and is 11 years old at least. I would say that *anything* can happen with such version.. As a general answer, altering defaults should not corrupt data but it is good practice to take a backup anyway.

Comment: @jkavalik haha! Unfortunately I have to say yes, this is what is in production.

Comment: Creating a test table with defaults, populating it with some data then running a script like the one in your question on that table – wouldn't seem to be much of a risk to me, especially if you do all that on a non-production server instance. And by the way, your syntax may be slightly off, see [How to alter a column and change the default value?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/142228/mysql-update-the-defualt-table-schema-on-production-server).

Comment: @AndriyM  Yep, I'll start working on test cases now.

Comment: The columns are `NULL`, why worry about the `DEFAULT`?